# whats wrong with this JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

firebug is complaining its there is a syntax error

```
if (document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "") || 
(document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "Enter Address, City, Directions") {
```

Comment: You should put a bit more code in the question so we can have some context here. Assuming there is more code after the {, you might put in something like {...} so we know it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis, that being said you are better off writing it like this.

```
var from = document.getElementById("fromAddress").value;
if (from  === "" || from  === "Enter Address, City, Directions") {
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the ***entire*** conditional statement in parans:

```
if ( (blah) || (blah) )
   ^                  ^
{
  // as you were
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have ***mis-match of parenthesis***, try this:

```
if ((document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "") || 
(document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "Enter Address, City, Directions")){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected form: (removed  2  parentheses)

if (document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "" || 
document.getElementById("fromAddress").value == "Enter Address, City, Directions") {